# Improper ParametricPlot3D result when using certain complex numbers

Tags: plotting, bugs, graphics3d, complex

**Bug introduced in 8 or earlier and persisting in 11.1**

---

This is more out of curiosity than for any project that I'm working on.

I was experimenting with the ParametricPlot3D and put in the following code:

`ParametricPlot3D[{x, Im[(-1)^(5 x)], Im[(-1)^(5 x)]}, {x, 0, 1}]`.

For some odd reason I didn't get a waveform that was tilted 45 degrees but instead a flatline.  Does anyone know why this is?  I contacted Wolfram Research about it weeks ago and I haven't heard from them.  It doesn't do this if I use `Im[E^(I*Pi*x*5)], Im[(-1)^(x*5)]`, then it works perfectly it is only a problem if I base it around -1.

A screenshot of the output is below. [image]

Comment: I'm more interested in why this occurs, I know how to get the Sin[pi*x*5] waveform titled at 45 degrees, I just don't know why it does this when I use a base of -1.

Answer (score 2):

```
ex = Im@ComplexExpand[(-1)^(5 x)]
ParametricPlot3D[{x, ex, ex}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: `ex = Assuming[Element[x, Reals], 
  Simplify@Im@ComplexExpand[(-1)^(5 x)]]` or `ex = Assuming[Element[x, Reals], FullSimplify@Im[(-1)^(5 x)]]` will evaluate to `Sin[5*Pi*x]`

Comment: @BobHanlon yes I appreciate that (-1)^5=exp(5Pi x) and hence the imaginary part is Sin[5 Pi x] and by inspection could have just substituted it into ParametricPlot3D. I interpreted the question as how to get MMA to interpret. I agree that your expression shows this explicitly. I accept it as a constructive comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
ParametricPlot3D[
  {x, 
   Evaluate[Im[(-1)^(5 x)]], 
   Evaluate[Im[(-1)^(5 x)]]},
 {x, 0, 1}]
```

or

```
ParametricPlot3D[
       Evaluate /@ {x, Im[(-1)^(5 x)], Im[(-1)^(5 x)]},
       {x, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: Or `ParametricPlot3D[
 Simplify@{x, Im[(-1)^(x*5)], Im[(-1)^(x*5)]}, {x, 0, 1}]` or `ParametricPlot3D[
 ComplexExpand@{x, Im[(-1)^(x*5)], Im[(-1)^(x*5)]}, {x, 0, 1}]`

Comment: `Evaluate` does nothing unless it is in the first level of holding expression.

Comment: even just this fixes it.. `ParametricPlot3D[{Evaluate@x, Im[(-1)^(5 x)], Im[(-1)^(5 x)]}, {x, 0, 1}]` bizarre..